# Combine large amounts of files inside a directory

Tags: bash, cat

I have a large amount of files within a single directory, currently 10,804 files. the amount of files can float between 5 and 100,000.

I am looking for a way to combine every 250 separate files into one large file with the remainder in a small file. 
for example 1200 files
I want 4 files with 250 and 1 file with 200

I am using bash shell.

Comment: You want to concatenate groups of the files into big files, or you want to move groups of the files into subdirectories?

Comment: ... or are you looking at creating `tar` archives of the files?

Comment: I want to cat groups of files into big files

Comment: the overall goal is to have small files to send to the printer, cat * creates a massive file that goes over the print buffers. sending individual files takes way to long for processing at the printer

Comment: thanks everyone for the help, I was able to find a solution that worked for my needs.

Comment: DIRPATH="DIRPATH"
files_count=`ls -1 ${DIRPATH} | wc -l`
block_size=250
block_count="$((${files_count}/${block_size}))"
count=1

while [[ ${count} -le ${block_count} ]]
do
 files=`find *.ps | head -${block_size}`
 for j in ${files}
 do
  cat $j >> outfile$count
  mv $j ${archive}/$j
 done
 let count=${count}+1
done
# catchs all remaining files under block_size
cat *.ps > last_bundle

exit 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
files_count=`ls -1 ./ | wc -l`
block_size=10
blocks_count=$(($files_count/$block_size))

for i in $(seq 1 1 $blocks_count); do
    files=`find . -type f -exec readlink -f {} \; | head -$block_size`
    for j in $files; do
        if [ -f $j ] && [[ "$j" != outfile* ]] ; then
            cat $j >> outfile$i
    fi
    done
done
# remainder part
for i in *; do
    if [ -f $i ] && [[ "$i" != outfile* ]] ; then
        cat $i >> outfilelast
    fi
done
```

**Note:**

> Your files merged alphabetically and also script should be placed inside the same directory.

Comment: Hi I tried this and I am getting the following error : files_count=  10805
+ block_size=250
+ blocks_count=43
+ seq 1 1 43
seq: not found
+ [ ! -f outfilelast ]
+ exit 0
$

Comment: I updated the answer.check again.place the script inside same folder or modify script carefully.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a straightforward loop to do this with an array and [`${x:s:l}` parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
files=(*)
for (( i = 0; i < ${#files[@]}; i += 250 ))
do
    cat -- "${files[@]:$i:250}" > "file$i.combined"
done
```

Here we collect all the (non-hidden) files in `.` into an array `files` (file names sorted lexically), and loop over counting from 0 to however many files there are in 250s. For each 250, we expand out the filenames (0-249, 250-499, etc) as arguments to `cat` and put the output into `file0.combined`, `file250.combined`, and so on.

This is just Bash's version of a traditional C-style `for` loop. Since you're going to have to loop for each separate `cat` anyway, there's not much point overcomplicating things.

You'll end up with several `.combined` files at the end - because the filenames were already expanded, those won't be included in the concatenations again, but if you ran the command a second time they would be. If that's a concern, you could put them somewhere else, delete them afterwards, or if it's going straight to the printer even just pipe to `lp`.

Comment: Hi I'm getting a syntax error - syntax error: got <&, expecting Word

Comment: What did you write when you got that error? Did it give a location? What shell are you running?

Comment: it appears to not like the files=(*).... shell is #!/bin/bash

Comment: I'm not sure how there's a syntax error on that line where the error is about something that isn't on that line. Can you post 1) the full error report and 2) the full line on which it reports that error?

Comment: got a different error after tying again ... ./bcnbd430.sh 15: syntax error: got (, expecting Newline       line 15 -> files=(*)

Comment: Either this is a decades-old Bash version without arrays, or something is wrong earlier in your script. What happens if you take those added lines out?

Comment: If I change file=(*)   to file=`ls *`     I get ./bcnbd430.sh 12: syntax error: got <&, expecting Word ----- which is the "for" line

Comment: I am using bash built within MKS tool kit Version 10.1.0 build 4400, Date Apr 14 2017 13:13:53

Comment: So, not actually Bash? I have no idea what this shell does, then. `<&` is clearly not on that line, so who knows what it's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below method

```
for ((i=1;i<=1200;i++)); do j=$(($i + 249 )); sed -n ''$i','$j'p' filename >individual_$i ;i=$j; done
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and it doesnt like the for loop   for ((i=1;i<=15050;i++));    I get the following error - ./bcnbd430.sh 16: syntax error: got <&, expecting Word

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are okay with combining them in the order `find` finds them:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -L 250 sh -c 'cat "$@" >/tmp/combined-${1##*/}' sh
```

For a directory containing files with names `file-1` up to `file-739` (as an example), this would create files in `/tmp` called `combined-file-1`,
`combined-file-251`, and `combined-file-501`, where the bit after `combined-` is the name of the first file in that combined file.

It does this by calling `cat` to concatenate files in batches of a maximum of 250 files at a time in an in-line shell script executed repeatedly by `xargs` (the `${1##*/}` in that script removes any directory path from the current batch's first file's pathname). The `xargs` utility gets the filenames as nul-terminated strings from `find`.  The `find` utility will look in the current directory (only) and output all pathnames therein that corresponds to regular files.

You would then print the `/tmp/combined-*` files.

To only process files with a particular suffix, like `.txt`, use `-name '*.txt'` in the `find` command, before `-print0`.

The `-print0` action of `find` and the `-0` option of `xargs` are non-standard by commonly implemented.

Comment: Hi I tried this and I get the following + DIRPATH=/E=/NBIPTEST/unprocessed/
+ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0
+ xargs -0 -L 250 sh -c cat "$@" >${unprocessed}/combined-${1##*/} sh
xargs: Unknown option "-0"

Usage: xargs [-l#][-L #] [-irepl][-I repl] [-n#] [-tpx] [-s#] [-eeof][-E eof] [cmd [args ...]]
Unknown option "-maxdepth"
Usage: find directory ... expression
+ exit 0

Comment: After removing the code that flags as an error I am left with find . -type f | xargs -L 250 sh -c 'cat "$@" >${unprocessed}/combined-${1##*/}' sh     and this freezes when running

Comment: @gizmo You can't just delete bits of a command without understanding what the new command does!!!  What Unix are you on?

Comment: I agree, but trying to isolate where the first error is coming from, and seeing if there was a way to fix it before I commented back here